# BSOD during Windows 7 64 bit installation - Dell Inspirion R15 3537

Tags: windows-7, bsod, dell-inspiron

I recently bought Inspiron 15 3537 with Windows 8. I am trying to install fresh Windows 7 instead. I followed all the instructions, yet at the end of the installation I get the blue screen with HIDCLASS.SYS error:

[image]

Someone know how to fix it? :(

Comment: Post the screenshot through a comment.  What instructions exactly did you follow?

Comment: I followed the instructions from here: http://superuser.com/questions/541472/how-to-clean-install-windows-7-professional-64bit-on-dell-inspiron-15r-turbo-s/709324?noredirect=1#comment906370_709324. My question was first posted as comment there. Here is the screenshot: http://i33.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0131/88/0559afa5ee77dae010f6f5439252e088.jpg

Comment: Those instructions make no sense.  Windows 7 supports UEFI and GPT.  You shouldn't have to boot enable legacy mode to install Windows 7.

Comment: hidclass = input device (keyboard, mouse). remove an attached mouse.

Comment: what was the issue? The mouse?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Can you post it to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same symptoms on my Dell M4700 Laptop. Unfortunately, removing all USB devices and starting over did NOT solve the problem for me.

What *did* work was booting into the BIOS and clicking the 'Reset  to Factory Defaults' button (GUI BIOS). Once the factory default settings were applied, Windows 7 x64 installed without any Blue Screens. It took me awhile to figure this out since I had not modified the BIOS settings on this laptop. I was just at the end of my rope and happened to stumble across this.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the comments, I removed the my Microsoft wireless keyboard and mouse receiver from the USB. It worked.

Then I plugged-in a basic keyboard and mouse (I always have a backup just in case) and completed the setup.

Comment: You're my hero, the wind beneath my wings. I've spent the last few days trying to reinstall Win 7 64-bit on a Dell Optiplex 980 system. It blue screens near the end of the install and after a reboot tells me that I need to reinstall. I switched from a wireless Microsoft mini keyboard to a different keyboard and the install worked fine. I was considering giving up on this system.