# Windows 7 "Setup is starting" freezes

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, setup, hp-pavilion

I have HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook PC ,it came with 2 drives, C & Recovery. I re-partitioned the hard using a windows 7 bootable dvd, I deleted the 2 drives, and then created a C and another one, installed the windows on the C and everything was ok until I restarted the computer, the windows didn't start, I forced it shut down, and then tried to re-install the windows again but it freezes on 'Setup is starting' screen.

I searched the problem, solutions like 'disable fdd' or 'disable non-essentials' didn't work, actually the bios screen doesn't give me many options, the menus are :

Main -- the device features

Security -- Power-on password

Diagnostics -- Primary Hard Disk & Memory test

System Configuration -- Language, Card Reader / 1349 Power Saving, Fan always On (enable/disable) & Boot options.

I even tried to boot from a USB drive but this too didn't work, since the Boot options only supports the following:

CD-ROM, Floppy & Internal Network Adapter boot.

Could this be a Hardware problem ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Was it freezing before you started to format/re-install Windows?

Comment: Nope, before the re-installing and the re-partitioning it wasn't freezing.

Comment: So, it is most likely due to your changes, so why do you think it could be hardware? Is there anything else which suggests hardware? If not, consider re-installing the OS again.

Comment: I don't know !
It's just that nothing seems to work, so I was wondering if the cause was hardware.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. The fact the hardware was OK suggests that it will remain OK (unless you physically opened the machine up during the reinstallation)...  I would try and re-install it

Comment: that's a relief :)
but again, I have a problem re-installing the Windows, it says:
"Setup is starting" and then nothing happens, it gets stuck there !

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments, it's not likely to be a hardware issue, much more likely to be either

a faulty installation of the OS
missing OS drivers
fault reading the harddrive (hard drive or faulty cable)

So, first off, check out why it's freezing, via the Event Log, or check the mini dumps if you get the BSOD.

Use Windows Updates to make sure you have the latest drivers, although to be honest, if you know the manufacturer of the hardware (CPU, Graphics and Audio etc) then you're better going to their website to download the latest drivers direct)

If these provide nothing, try reformatting and reinstalling the OS again.

If you can't get this far, then it is probably a faulty install - put in the W7 disc, and start the machine. Hit <kbd>F8</kbd> to get the boot menu, and choose to boot from DVD

Comment: I can't enter to the windows, so the updating isn't an option, and also I am stuck installing the Windows, it's says "Setup is starting" and then nothing happens.

Comment: You need to make sure the computers boots to the DVD drive. This can be changed in the BIOS or by pressing F8

Comment: It does boot, but the installation freezes for some reason !
I don't know how to check the Event Log either.

Comment: I found something called 'Diagnostic Log' and it showed a list of Results and the corresponding time, example:

0303    --    02142014-132222
0601    --    10142013-134637

Comment: I searched for 0303 --> and it says that the hard drive may have failed.
:(

Comment: I think that is your answer @Nour... I suggest you back up if you can. Leave the hard drive alone, put it into another machine as a slave and take a back up! If it's the hard drive (then it *is* hardware) then take the machine back..

Answer (score 1):

I had the [same issue with my Dell Inspirion 15R SE](https://superuser.com/a/583227/174557). The cause of the hang is the [Graphics Output Protocol (GOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Graphics_features). Windows 7 doesn't support it and hangs here. The solution was to enable the old VGA option ROM loading (disabling fastBoot) in the UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be your created partition didn't meet the minimum system requirements. Consequently, all your data will be removed. Try to do factory reset to bring back all things. However, you should unplug first whatever additional device such as usb or printer then do the following:

1. **Go to control panel**
2. **Select recovery manager**
3. **Click system recovery**
4. The recovery manager will ask if you want to restore into original factory shipped. **Click yes**.
5. **Your computer will restart and you hard drive will start functioning**.

If your computer didn't start when you press the power button. Just press F11 and recovery manager will appear. Nevertheless, if you need to recover your computer through recovery disk. You can do the following:

1. **Turn on your computer and insert the recovery disk**.
2. **Turn off your computer**.
3. **Unplug your usb and printer.**
4. **Turn on your computer**
5. **Press Esc key immediately and repeat every second until select boot device menu open**.
6. If select boot menu open. **Choose the selection by arrow up**. On the other hand,**if start menu open instead of boot menu**. **Press F9**
7. Two selection will appear recovery from hard drive or disk. Select **Run Program from disk** then **select next**.
8. Choose the recovery option based on your type of recovery disk.

I hope this will help.