# Microsoft Surface Pro 3 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-surface

Is it possible to install Windows 7 on Microsoft Surface Pro 3? I would like to buy it but I don't like Windows 8 (and later versions).

Comment: Yes provided you can drivers for all the devices which will be tough since there are none for the touch screen

Comment: Windows 8 isn't that bad! It's pretty good lol... plus, because you're running a Pro, you could run Windows 7 as a VM in VirtualBox or something.

Comment: It should be possible and not just 'in theory'. As far as I'm aware part of Bootcamp's functionality is providing a BIOS emulation layer over the top of it's EFI. Other projects like BAMBIOS have done the same to different degrees of success over the years. If one were to use a boot loader like rEFIt initially then provide a BIOS emulation from there for Win7 I can't see any reason for it not to work. There needs to be sufficient motivation for someone sufficiently skilled to put the pieces together though...

Comment: The 8.1 version isn't so bad as it's made out to be, and it really does have some nice things that will specifically work well on a surface or similar device.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 doesn't work on the Surface Pro. Microsoft explained it here::

**Windows 7 Setup hangs at "Starting Windows" on Surface Pro**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828074/en-us

> The Surface Pro is a Class 3 UEFI device that does not support legacy
>   BIOS Interrupt 10 (INT 10H) video transitioning and it requires
>   Windows 8 or later operating systems to run.

You should install [StartIsBack+](http://startisback.com/) when you use the Surface most of the time in desktop mode and don't want to use the startscreen.

Comment: Then how do people install Windows 7 on other UEFI laptops ? And will booting in BIOS mode work

Comment: @SuiciDoga the UEFI must offer VGA/option ROM like my Dell Inspiron: http://superuser.com/a/583227/174557 Here I run Win7 in UEFI mode